# Control panel application does not work

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a simple *.cpl applet which calls a *.exe file.

I have this code:

```
uses
  shellapi;

procedure TAppletModule1AppletModule.AppletModuleActivate(Sender: TObject;
  Data: Integer);
begin
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'Control Panel_betteryless.exe', '', '', SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

When I double-click Project1.cpl, nothing happens. When I copy Project1.cpl in the System32 directory, no additional entry will be added in the control panel.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE** Here is the actual scenario I am trying to do:

A vendor of a digitizer has released their drivers in 2011. They are not compatible with Windows 10. It was fully compatible with Windows 7. However, I found a few tweaks how to enforce the compatiblity, so the device works now.

The driver includes a CPL named **tablet.cpl** and **Control Panel_betteryless.exe** [sic!] , which are installed in **System32** . Somehow, the installer did not register **tablet.cpl** . Running **Control Panel_betteryless.exe** via doubleclick works. Now I wanted to let this CPL or EXE appear in the control panel (in the end, I want to modify the driver, so I have a "fixed driver" for future installations).

I have created following registry entry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cpls\tablet.cpl]
"RunLevel"=dword:00000000
```

But in the control panel, no item gets added.

Just to be sure that the CPL is not defect, I have copied `telephon.cpl` as `tablet.cpl` and tried it again. I would expect that the Telephony entry would be now twice in the control panel. But nothing changed.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951440/control-panel-win7-applets). `.cpl` files have to be registered in the Registry (`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cpls\<AppletName>.cpl`) so the Control Panel can find them, as they can reside anywhere on the HDD.  Dropping them into the system folder is not enough.  Also, starting in Vista, Control Panel applets do not have to be implemented as `.cpl` files anymore, they can now be implemented as standard `.exe` files that have been registered as command objects.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. Alas, it doesn't work. I have added the CPL exactly as you told, in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cpls\xx.cpl` , but nothing happens. I also tried to register an EXE like told in MSDN. Doesn't work either. The "install in control panel" in Delphi XE4 also doesn't work. I have no idea why I get "-3" because of a question where I really try to find a solution - all the tutorials, even the one included in Delphi 6 didn't work for me.

Comment: Where you are getting -3 from?  Please update your question with all the relevant details about what you have actually done so far.

Comment: Done. Actually, I only included the important details. My ShellExecute-idea does not seem to be important, as I wanted to do this solution because I didn't know about the registration of EXE files.

Comment: See [Registering Control Panel Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144195.aspx). Also, are you running on a 32bit or 64bit version of Windows, and is the `.cpl` file 32bit or 64bit? If you are trying to register a 32bit `.cpl` on a 64bit Windows, and if you want to put the file in the system folder, you have to use `c:\windows\syswow64` instead of `c:\windows\system32`. Otherwise, put the `.cpl` file in your own folder and register the location of the file, as described in the link above.

Comment: I have a 64-bit Windows 10 and a 32-bit CPL. I copied the CPL in SysWow64 , but it doesn't work with my *.reg script above. It confuses me why it doesn't work, because other CPLs are defined the same way: They have a single key, e.g. "joy.cpl" with the DWORD RunLevel=0 .

Comment: Did you reboot after copying the file?

Comment: Yes, I just did it. Nothing new added in control panel. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85479/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-rinntech).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a 32bit `.cpl` file in the `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64` folder, and a 64bit `.cpl` file in the `%SystemRoot%\System32` folder, and both will appear in the Control Panel without having to register them.  However, if you want to store the `.cpl` file somewhere else, you have to register it explicitly, as described in the documentation:

[How to Register DLL Control Panel Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127454.aspx)

For example:

32bit

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cpls

  [REG_EXPAND_SZ] "MyCpl" = "%ProgramFiles%\MyApp\MyApplet.cpl"
```

64bit

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cpls

  [REG_EXPAND_SZ] "MyCpl" = "%ProgramFiles%\MyApp\MyApplet.cpl"
```

Regardless of where you place the `.cpl` file, by default the applet will only appear in the Control Panel when its "View by" field is set to either "Large icons" or "Small icons".  If you want the applet to appear inside of a particular category instead, you have to register that, for example:

32bit

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Contro‌​l Panel\Extended Properties\System.ControlPanel.Category

  [REG_DWORD] "%ProgramFiles%\MyApp\MyApplet.cpl" = 1
```

64bit

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Contro‌​l Panel\Extended Properties\System.ControlPanel.Category

  [REG_DWORD] "%ProgramFiles%\MyApp\MyApplet.cpl" = 1
```

Use `REG_SZ` instead of `REG_DWORD` if you want the applet to appear in multiple categories.  The actual numbers are documented here:

[Assigning Control Panel Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144183.aspx)

In my examples here, I am using the `Appearance and Personalization` category.

Now, with that said, a Delphi 32bit `.cpl` works fine on Windows 10, but a 64bit `.cpl` crashes on Windows 10 with two popup `EAccessViolation` messages before the `TAppletModule.OnActivate` event is then triggered (the `EAccessViolation` errors do not occur on Windows 7).  I do not know why it crashes, maybe Microsoft changed something in the `CplApplet()` API during applet initialization that `TAppletModule` is not accounting for (I don't have Delphi installed on Windows 10 to debug it).  However, `.cpl` is legacy anyway, and should not be used for new applets.  You can register `Control Panel_betteryless.exe` itself to appear directly in the Control Panel, per the documentation:

[How to Register Executable Control Panel Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127450.aspx)

For example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace\{guid}

  (Default) = "betteryless"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{guid}

  (Default) = "betteryless"
  [REG_SZ] "System.ControlPanel.Category" = "1"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{guid}\Shell\Open\Command

  (Default) = [REG_EXPAND_SZ] "%SystemRoot%\System32\Control Panel_betteryless.exe"
```

Where `{guid}` is a GUID that you create, such as with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> keyboard combo in Delphi's code editor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent answer! A small annotation for others who might have a similar problem: To create a REG_EXPAND_SZ , an additional tool need to be invoked, because RegEdit doesn't have this capatiblity.

`REG ADD HKCR\CLSID\{guid}\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "%SystemRoot%\System32\Control Panel_betteryless.exe"`

Once done, the result can be exported as *.reg .

Comment: To be more specific, only the `(Default)` value cannot be created as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` using RegEdit. Other values can be. `(Default)` can be created as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` in code using `RegSetValueEx()`, or via the command-line `reg.exe` utility, or in a `.reg` file using the `hex(2)` syntax.